# setting first responder on modal sheet

Tags: swift, macos

So I want to ask the user, via sheet, something in a modal dialog:

```
class MyTextView : NSTextView {
    override func viewWillDraw() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)
        }
    }
}

private func requestNotification() {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.InformationalAlertStyle
    alert.messageText = "Enter your email address"

    let urlField = MyTextView.init(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,300,28))
    let urlScroll = NSScrollView.init(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,300,28))
    urlScroll.hasVerticalScroller = true
    urlScroll.autohidesScrollers = true
    urlField.drawsBackground = true
    urlField.editable = true

    urlScroll.documentView = urlField
    alert.accessoryView = urlScroll

    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Send")
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")

    alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.window!, completionHandler: { response in
        if response == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
            // Send
            let view = (alert.accessoryView as! NSScrollView).documentView as! NSTextView
            let text = view.string! as String
            self.webViewController.loadAlmostURL(text)
        }
    })
}
```

which functions a lot better then attempts with an NSTextField.

At least the interaction starts with entry, but, I'd like to border the text view?

Comment: Well, sub-classing NSTextField I can make it the first responder but the editing overlaps like something wasn't loaded right; I'll update the original with this.

Comment: Using NSTextView instead; however this then leads to another issue needing to embed it into a scroll view, which in turn requires constraints to allow vertical scrolling to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet pretty much does it all, except the border rect as in an NSTextField.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to do this with a NSTextField, the repeated calls to viewWillDraw seem to interfere with the blinking cursor and tabbing through the dialog. To fix that, set a flag in the viewWillDraw routine to only set the firstResponder once, something like this:

```
class AlertTextField : NSTextField {

    var doOnce = true
    override func viewWillDraw() {
        if doOnce {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)
                self.doOnce = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```